# Generar objeto array JSON de una lista tipo Object

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

Estoy generando primeramente un objeto dinámico con: `dynamic objetoTabla = new ExpandoObject();`, el cual yo le agrego las propiedades dinámicamente según la data que genero con *LINQ*, hasta ahí todo va bien, seguidamente ese objeto creado lo almaceno en una lista tipo `Object`. Al final hago una conversión:

```
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lista);
```

... y retorno:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = data, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Todo eso me retorna la siguiente cadena:

> "[{\"Estado\":\"1.1 EN SERVICIO\",\"BALESIA\":22,\"Total\":160,\"CT\":81,\"TA\":23,\"TORRESEC\":27,\"TU\":7},{\"Estado\":\"2.1 EN INSTALACION\",\"BALESIA\":2,\"Total\":22,\"CT\":11,\"TA\":8,\"TORRESEC\":1,\"TU\":0}]"

Lo cual está mal, ya que me pone las comillas al principio del array y las barras invertidas dentro de los objetos. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿El tipo de objeto se convierte a JSON de otra manera?

Necesito un array JSON, porque eso es lo que mi tabla *angular* necesita. Uso *dynamic* porque mi tabla angular es dinámica, y se arma según las propiedades del JSON.

Estoy trabajando en MVC4, C#.

Comment: Desde angular como haces el llamado a esa funcion?

Comment: ¿Cuando hace la conversion a var data, el string es igual?

Comment: Ese texto lo ves en Visual Studio o es lo que te llega al cliente? porque parece ser un simple "escapado" para las comillas internas, las comillas externas son porque es un string.

Comment: si, el texto lo veo igual en visual studio, alguien me puede pasar un link donde pueda aprender a generar este tipo de servicios json?. porfavor

Comment: Estas retornando el Json de un Json, JsonResult te serializa automáticamente el objeto que le regresas, solo regresa la lista.

Comment: Tiene razón el compañero Alejandro Cervantes: ¡estás serializando dos veces!

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que está bien lo que estás haciendo. Te está retornando un *JSON* contenido en un *string*, las barras invertidas que ves son para escapar a las comillas, lo único que te faltaría hacer, cuando lo recibís desde el lado del cliente, es:

```
var jsonString = "[{\"Estado\":\"1.1 EN SERVICIO\",\"BALESIA\":22,\"Total\":160,\"CT\":81,\"TA\":23,\"TORRESEC\":27,\"TU\":7},{\"Estado\":\"2.1 EN INSTALACION\",\"BALESIA\":2,\"Total\":22,\"CT\":11,\"TA\":8,\"TORRESEC\":1,\"TU\":0}]";
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Si probás esto en la consola, veras que se convierte sin problemas.

Igualmente, si lo que querés es que no te aparezcan los nombres de las propiedades (Balesia, CT, Estado, etc) encerrados entre comillas, podés probar con la siguiente solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967885/how-to-convert-object-to-json-with-jsonconvert-without-key-qoutations

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es crear una clase que tenga las propiedades que generas en LINQ, ya que al convertirlo a JSON con Newtonsoft; no es capaz de realizar la conversión de las propiedades dinámicas.

Quizas quieras ahorrarte unas lineas de código usando dynamic, pero debes usarlo creando un DTO.

Deberias tener algo asi

```
public class Detalle { 
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public int BALESIA { get; set; }
    ...
}

List<Detalle> detalles = (from x in ... db...... select new Detalle { ..... }).ToList();
return new JsonResult { Data = detalles, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```